# Why is there a required build step for Web UI apps?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Why must we run a build.dart script to develop with web_ui ?

I thought it was an frequent noob question about web_ui but I do not find an answer about that. Maybe I miss some web resources or articles.

With Angular.js or Polymer MDV don't need it, and they use bidirectionnal binding. 
With future version of Web_ui or Chronium version, does the build.dart will be still necessary ?

This side of web_ui disappoints me a little bit and I feel it could discourage developers to use it.

Another point is I don't like project organisation with HTML sources in "web" and another "web/out" directory ? Can we configure the script to have another out directory like "templates" for templates and "web" for output ? 
Than

Comment: Since you are asking several questions in one, I would suggest to break it up into smaller ones that can be answered separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `@observable`, then you need to run a code generation step. Because Dart is a more structured language, it's not currently possible to add methods or change structure of an object at runtime. Therefore, we must run through a small code generation step that converts `@observable` into the code to track and notify for changes.

Polymer doesn't need this because they can alter the object at runtime. Also, Object.observe is landing in V8 (already landed?) which means the runtime performs observability automatically.

We know this is a problem, and we have a few ideas on how to solve it.

1. Build a devserver that does the building for you automatically.
2. Implement (eventually) mirror builders, which would allow you to alter program structure at runtime.

Option 1 is a near-term solution, and option 2 is a long-term solution.